# wp_enqueue_script issue with wordpress and scrollmagic

Tags: javascript, wordpress, scrollmagic

I'm working on a website that uses the http://scrollmagic.io/ library. It's wodpress. On the header.php there's this script:

```
    <script>
// init controller
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
</script>
```

And there are more scripts on the page.php that I move to assets/JS.

The problem is, when I move the script above and some other scripts and call them with register script and wp_enqueue_script, somehow they're not working.

It's mean, when they on header.php / page.php they all work. However, when I create a .js files and call them with wp_enqueue_script, they just not working.

But, then, they all in the global scope, so the functions / object should work in different scripts? But then why they work on they place direct on page.php / header.php, but not work when I call them using wp_enqueue_script?

Any idea?

I was thinking, maybe they depend on each other (which they do, some of the scripts use the ScrollMagic.Controller(); (it's not Angular, just a function from the scrollmagic library). Could it be the problem? and if yes, is there a dependency management for wordpress / javascript?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are the scripts saved in individual .js files, or are you trying to register and enqueue them just like your code above - i.e. with the full <script>...</script> tags?

Comment: Of course in individual .js files (w/o <script> of course). there's js folder under assets folder and I just moved all the scripts there. Just to say that some scripts that were on page.php work fine. But some of them are not. Those scripts which depend on the script above (which they depend on the ScrollMagic, because the Controller method is from the ScrollMagic library)

Comment: If the scripts are dependent then the order would matter. I'd look into enqueueing with dependencies - you can specify by handle which depends on which.